# XSD validation with XmlSchemaSet does not find error

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a simple XML that we produce to a match a vendor's XSD, however, there is an error in the doc where we use `<deletePLU>` instead of `<domain:deletePLU>`.

The XSD uses a target namespace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:domain="urn:vfi-sapphire:np.domain.2001-07-01"
           elementFormDefault="unqualified"
           targetNamespace="urn:vfi-sapphire:np.domain.2001-07-01"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="PLUs"> ...
```

The code does not pick up on that and I don't know why.

**I assume with the missing domain namespace the "deletePLU" is attributed to the defautl namespace which has no schema?**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<domain:PLUs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:domain="urn:vfi-sapphire:np.domain.2001-07-01" page="1" ofPages="1">
     <domain:PLU>
        <upc>00853288005119</upc>
        <upcModifier>0</upcModifier>
        <description>SIX PACKS</description>
        <department>2</department>
        <fee>0</fee>
        <pcode>0</pcode>
        <price>10.19</price>
        <taxRates>
           <domain:taxRate sysid="2"/> 
        </taxRates>
        <idChecks>
           <domain:idCheck sysid="2"/> 
        </idChecks>
        <SellUnit>1.000</SellUnit> 
     </domain:PLU>
     <deletePLU>
        <upc>00751249241128</upc>
        <upcModifier>0</upcModifier>
     </deletePLU>
<domain:PLUs>
```

**The validation code is as follows:**
(I did use XDocument and XmlSchemaSet before rewriting the validation to this, neither one worked)

```
        // configure the xmlreader validation to use inline schema.
        var config = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
        config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

        var b = new StringBuilder();
        config.ValidationEventHandler += ( sender, vea ) =>
        {
          ...
        };

        config.Schemas = schemas;

        try
        {
            // Get the XmlReader object with the configured settings.
            var reader = XmlReader.Create( xmlDocFile.FullName, config );

            // Parsing the file will cause the validation to occur.
            while ( reader.Read() );

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {...}
```

**How can I make sure the document's error is discovered?**

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the XSD, maybe it actually allows deletePLU without namespace?

Comment: The XSD is gigantic. But no it does not allow that, since when loading the the XML into XML Studio 2014 using the same XSD to validate it, Xml Studio does output the error as expected -- "deletePLU" is missing the "domain" namespace.

Comment: @nodots you were right. The tag can be used without a namespace. I edited my question to incldue the XSD root. The question remains though, why is the validation not picking up the error?

Comment: I'm confused - can it be used without namespace, or is it an error? Could you show the <deletePLU> definition from the XSD? Is it in the same XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am unsure as to how to explain the problem in any more detail here is what I found to make this XSD validation work as expected.

Use the reader settings as had:

```
        var config = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
        };

        config.ValidationEventHandler += ConfigOnValidationEventHandler;

        config.Schemas = schemas;
```

The important part is that you DO NOT specify the `targetNamespace`. I used the overload `XmlShemaSet.Add(string targetNamespace, string schemaUri)`.

```
schemas.Add( null, "c:\test\mySchema.xsd" );
```

I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation on XmlReader, section *Validating XML data*, table with XmlReaderSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx#xmlreader_validate) (emphasis mine):

> ValidationEventHandler event
>  An event handler for receiving
>   information about validation events. **If an event handler is not
>   provided, an XmlException is thrown on the first validation error.**

Since you specify a `ValidationEventHandler`, the XmlReader invokes the handler but does not throw.